# Why does PreparedStatement (JDBC) result in a MySQLSyntaxErrorException in MySQL 5.7.9?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Code:

```
package com.qapro.register;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/RegisterMember")
public class RegisterMember extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RegisterMember() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qapro?user=root&password=root";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            String userInsertSql = "INSERT INTO qapro.user (user_name, `password`, is_active, name, surname, email, insert_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(userInsertSql);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            preparedStatement.setBoolean(3, true);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, name);           
            preparedStatement.setString(5, surname);
            preparedStatement.setString(6, email);
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(7, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

            int affectedRowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(userInsertSql);
            if(affectedRowCount > 0)
                System.out.println("User has been inserted succesfully");
            else
                System.out.println("Error occurred while inserting user");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }

}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 
  <form action="RegisterMember" method="POST">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Log in!</legend>

     Username: <input type="text" name="username"></input>
     <br></br>
     Name: <input type="text" name="name"></input>
     <br></br>
     Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"></input>
     <br></br>
     Email: <input type="email" name="email"></input>
     <br></br>
     Password: <input type="password" name="password"></input>
     <br></br>
  
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
     
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 
 </body>

</html>
```

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?)' at line 1

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDIGZ.png)

Why do I get this error?
And eventhough this error occurs my database is updating.

Comment: How do you check if your JDBC driver supports it? 
And my rdbsm is MySQL and yes, i have it set as datatype BIT

Comment: You can check that by reading the documentation of the driver.

Comment: What is the exact version of your MySQL (server) installation and which exact version of the mysql-connector-xyz.jar are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.9 and mysql connector java 5.1.37

Comment: "eventhough this error occurs my database is updating" means there is an increasing number of "Jason" tuples in your "user" table, right? Why should this be the case when a MySQLSyntaxErrorException is thrown? sounds pretty buggy at driver level?!

Comment: @MWiesner - I suspect that there is something else going on in their actual code that they are not showing us.

Comment: @GordThompson - we tried pretty much everything already ;) - *thinking...

Comment: @MWiesner I added the entire project

Comment: So I've wasted 1h of my lifetime thinking on something hidden in your mind and in your IDE. *cheers :/ - please, next time, provide the full picture when asking people for help on complex problems/code.

Comment: @MWiesner  I really didnt believe that that was my problem, Im still a scrub, Truly sry.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Programming is not about "believe" it is about facts and things that are logical... Really: Please, learn from this story... people willing to help on StackOverflow need to be given precise and isolated questions, else we all waste time on nothing but speculation. You should award @GordThompson by accepting/upvoting if it helped you and you finally got a solution on your problem.

Comment: @MWiesner Very true.. Yes I understand that, thx for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```java
int affectedRowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(userInsertSql);
```

to try and execute the query, but that is incorrect. You have already used `userInsertSql` in the `.prepareStatement(userInsertSql)` call, so all you need to do is

```java
int affectedRowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: sadly to other users, the original mistake was edited away already, so it does not fit to the code in the question itself anymore... :-|